# Element can't be accessed when using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to log in to linked in and access the "My network" element. I've tried using id, class, xpath, and nothing works. I also tried waiting for 10 secs for the page to load so that python can access the site but that gives an error too. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

username=input("Enter linkedin mail id: ")
password=input("Enter password: ")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://in.linkedin.com/")

search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav__button-secondary")
search.click()

# logging in to linkedin

search=driver.find_element_by_id("username")
search.send_keys(username)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
search=driver.find_element_by_id("password")
search.send_keys(password)
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login__form_action_container ")
search.click()

search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@ID='ember748']")   # DOESNT WORK    
search.click()
```

I'm able to log in to LinkedIn using my username and password but after that, trying to access my network throws an error. What mistake am I making here?

This is what pops up in cmd:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61153/devtools/browser/4a54a771-4361-4304-a2df-7a366a4f31cc
[27720:25060:0412/123447.314:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [12:34:47.315] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1056 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

This is the error I'm getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vedha\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Internship\linkedinT1.py", line 32, in 
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@ID='ember748']")   # DOESNT WORK
File "C:\Users\vedha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\vedha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\vedha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\vedha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@ID='ember748']"}
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

Comment: `throws an error` what error?

Comment: I'm just gonna copy paste:

Comment: I've edited the post, pls refer.

Comment: seems like the id in the xpath is not static, Could you check reloading page and the same xpath works after couple of reloading of the page.

Comment: it is,,,what do i do??

Comment: What is it matching or not?, If not matching every time you reload the page, then you have to change the xpath, with something static.

Comment: but i tried the same using class id and everything, it still wont work

Comment: Check the same, whether the class returns you unique element every time page reloads. Check if the elements is inside iframe